Foreflight API to generate a flight plan and weather brief hyperlinks
I need to generate web hyperlinks for the ForeFlight flight plan and weather briefing in my daily routine. Is there a way to script this for flight plans I have saved in the flights tab? I normally performed this operation manually by saving the flight plan in flights and then using the flights -> share -> copy buttons on the app to copy the hyperlink.
Ideally I want to interact with the ForeFlight API, not make a workflow with the app or website versions of ForeFlight. Python and Jupyter Notebooks are my preferred tools, but I'm open to what works.
Any hints greatly appreciated. I will update this question until resolved.
